# How to start the android standard mediaplayer (with its standard ui) with file to play via intent?

Tags: android

I have an mp3 i save to sdcard if i start the MediaPlayer.play then it will just play it with no UI for forward,backward, so i just wanted to start the standard android media player so it will play my audio and in this way the user would be able interact with the media - forward backward etc.  (I saw some ui projects for mediaPlayer but i really want the standard android media player, isn't there some intent to it?)

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard way to do that:

```
Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
File file = new File(objectFilePath);   
viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");   
viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(viewMediaIntent);
```

If you change type to `"image/*"` you can see individual images, with `"video/*"` you play video files.

Comment: This is how i am doing this. But when the user presses the back button on the Player, i want the sound to stop playing. How to do this ?

Comment: I guess you can't directly, you can maybe when going back in your application ask for the audiofocus :/